# Nginx default page on docker

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose

```
// docker-compose.yml

    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
            # - ./site/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
            - ./site/site.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/site.conf
            - ./site/site.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.conf
        links:
            - php
    php:
        build: ./php
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code

// site/site.conf

server {
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I have the above configuration for nginx running inside docker. For some reason it keeps on showing the default nginx page.

Inside the container there is a file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` which includes all the `*.conf` from the `conf.d` directory but still unable to get my conf worked.

Then i tried copying my files into sites-available and sites-enabled folders still no luck.

Kindly help
Thanks

Comment: "there is a file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf which includes all the *.conf from the conf.d" but you've commented that out. Does the file get put inside the folders you've specified?

Comment: Also you have no `listen` directive in your context.

Comment: @miken32 that i commented out because i was trying sites available and enabled thing. It didn't work any case. The only way it worked is on the container start time i removed the default.conf file in conf.d folder and copy my site.conf file there. But this doesn't look like a proper solution

Comment: Does the file get put into the folder? Have you tried it with a `listen` directive?

Answer (score 3):

There are three things we need to do to get nginx up and running.

1. Delete **/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf** during the build process.
2. Make an **upstream** directive to properly reference the php-fpm service.
3. Alter the nginx user's **UID** to match yours.

The most efficient solution is to create a **Dockerfile** that solves all three of these nginx issues and put it in **docker-compose.yml**'s nginx service definition. This config helps correct the nginx user and includes `sites-enabled/.conf`

```
# /etc/nginx/nginx.conf: Changes user to www-data and includes /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log off;
  error_log off;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
  open_file_cache max=100;
}

daemon off;
```

Both the previous **nginx.conf** and this **Dockerfile** should be stored in the same directory.

```
# <your-nginx-build-context>/Dockerfile
FROM nginx:latest

# The default nginx.conf DOES NOT include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY symfony.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/

# Solves 1
RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ \
    && ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/symfony.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/symfony.conf \
    && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Solves 2
RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server php:9000; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf

# Solves 3
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

CMD ["nginx"]

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Make sure to update the nginx service definition in **docker-compose.yml** with something like:

```
web:
    build: ./nginx/Dockerfile
```